# SQL Server: Duplicates but based on specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find duplicates based on forename, surname, and dateofbirth in my database. Below is what I have

Customers table:

```
custid  cust_refno  forename surname dateofbirth
1           10        David   John     10-02-1980
2           20        Peter   Broad    15-08-1978
3           30        Sarah   Holly    16-09-1982
4           40        Mathew  Mark     25-08-2001
5           50        Matt    Mark     25-08-2001
```

Address table:

```
addid cust_refno addresstype   line1 
1       10         address     No. 10, Mineview Road
2       10         address     No. 20, Mineview Lane
3       20         address     Rockview cottage, blackthorn
4       30         mobile      0504135864
5       40         address     No. 64, New Lane 
6       40         mobile      0504896532
7       50         address     No. 11, John's cottage
```

Some customers have multiple addresses, so they are not duplicates. I am trying to find a way to avoid displaying those as duplicates. Can you advice how I can do that?

my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.CUST_REFNO, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH , a.LINE1 FROM CUSTOMERS AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ADDRESS a
ON t.CUST_REFNO = a.CUST_REFNO
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT FORENAME, surname, DTTM_OF_BIRTH
        FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY FORENAME, SURNAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS td 
    ON t.FORENAME = td.FORENAME AND t.DTTM_OF_BIRTH = td.DATE_OF_BIRTH
        AND t.SURNAME = td.SURNAME 
WHERE a.addresstype = 'address'
```

my result is:

```
Forename surname cust_refno dateofbirth line1 
David    John       10       10-02-1980  No. 10, Mineview Road
David    John       10       10-02-1980  No. 20, Mineview Lane
```

But in reality it is not a duplicate. Its just that the addresses are different. Is there a way to compare the cust_refno and see if it already exists so even if the address is different if the cust_refno is the same it does not show again?

Comment: In this case which one of the two lines do you want to get?

Comment: Is your goal to include only 1 address per customer? It would help to know exactly how you define "different". It is rather strange that you include mobile phone numbers in a table named address - perhaps that is a larger issue you should correct? That seems like a hack-like shortcut someone took to "get things done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to filter out customers with more than one address.  Then aggregation can be used to return the duplicates:

```
select forename, surname, dateofbirth
from customers c join
     (select a.*,
             count(*) over (partition by cust_refno) as cnt
      from addresses a
      where addresstype = 'address'
     ) a
     on c.cust_refno = a.cust_refno
where cnt = 1
group by forename, surname, dateofbirth
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want the full customer record, just use window functions twice:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             count(*) over (partition by forename, surname, dateofbirth) as cnt
      from customers c 
     ) c join
     (select a.*,
             count(*) over (partition by cust_refno) as cnt
      from addresses a
      where addresstype = 'address'
     ) a
     on c.cust_refno = a.cust_refno
where a.cnt = 1 and c.cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the customers with duplicates address, you can count how many times a customer has the same address and return just that with more than one:

```
SELECT t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.CUST_REFNO, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH , a.LINE1
FROM CUSTOMERS AS t INNER JOIN ADDRESS a ON t.CUST_REFNO = a.CUST_REFNO
GROUP BY t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.CUST_REFNO, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH , a.LINE1
HAVING COUNT(a.LINE1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function `count` and `row_number` as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.CUST_REFNO, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH , 
        a.LINE1,
        row_number() over (partition by t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH 
                           order by 1) as rn,
        count(1) over (partition by t.FORENAME, t.SURNAME, t.DATE_OF_BIRTH) as cnt
   FROM CUSTOMERS AS t 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ADDRESS a ON t.CUST_REFNO = a.CUST_REFNO
  WHERE a.addresstype = 'address') t
where cnt > 1 and rn = 1
```